# In Git, how to configure that 1 URL must be used instead of 2 URLs (by command)

Tags: git

In order to ask git to automatically replace in commands an URL by another one (ie. an anonymous https access to a local mirror instead of a ssh access to the distant reference repo), I use the command:

```
git config --global url.goodUrl.insteadOf badUrl1
```

and it works.
In my $HOME/.gitconfig file, I have:

```
[url goodUrl]
        insteadOf = badUrl1
```

But if I want to **use the same goodUrl** instead of another bad one (for example, a distant mirror defined in a submodule), I execute this second command:

```
git config --global url.goodUrl.insteadOf badUrl2
```

The config file is updated but **the badUrl1 setting is lost!**

It seems like we cannot define *by command* an URL to be used instead of 2 or more.

*Note: I tried editing the config file and adding the second URL, it works.*

```
[url goodUrl]
        insteadOf = badUrl1
        insteadOf = badUrl2
```

=> Do you know how to set in configuration 2 URLs to be replaced by another one, by command?

Comment: `git config --global -e` will open an editor and you can fix it. Not the most elegant solution but will work

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer!
1srt command (as written above): git config --global url.goodUrl.insteadOf badUrl1

The second command must be: git config --global **--add** url.goodUrl.insteadOf badUrl2